# How do I add packages on TeX Live 2018?

Tags: packages, texlive

I'm trying to install a package using TeX Live, and I already created the .sty file but I don't succeed in actually using the package, how do I add and use it?

Comment: If you want to use it for a single project, you can copy the `.sty` into the same folder as your main `.tex` and use `\usepackage{<name>}`, where `<name>` is the file name without `.sty`. If you want to make it available to all your projects, you can put it into your user's texmf. The path depends on your OS, on Linux it's usually `/home/<user>/texmf/`. Therein move your file to `tex/latex/<name>/<name>.sty`, again with `<name>` the name of your file without `.sty`.

Comment: where do I enter the \usepackage line?

Comment: After `\documentclass` and before `\begin{document}`. If you don't know this, perhaps it is a good idea to read a short introduction into LaTeX (e.g., [lshort](https://ctan.org/pkg/lshort)).